# Keep zooming (or zooming out) when mouse key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on the project where I need to do some kind of screen calibration.

This calibration works in the way that when the plus button is pressed "credit card" is zoomed in and when the minus button is pressed it is zoomed out for 0.5mm.

Everything works fine but when button is clicked "credit card" is just zoomed in or zoomed out for 0.5mm, so I need to keep clicking to change zoom further. I want zoom to be constant when mouse key is pressed and to stop zooming when released.

There is my JavaScript code:

```
var c = document.querySelector('.card'),
m = document.querySelector('.m'),
p = document.querySelector('.p'),
s = document.querySelector('.s'),
r = document.querySelector('.r'),
w = c.style.width = '54mm';

m.addEventListener('click', function() {
w = c.style.width = parseFloat(w) - 0.5 + 'mm';
});

p.addEventListener('click', function() {
w = c.style.width = parseFloat(w) + 0.5 + 'mm';
});

s.addEventListener('click', function() {
r.innerHTML = 54 / parseFloat(w);
});
```

You can look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mixerowsky/js5uwnyj/) to see the code that I'm using now. Can somebody help me with the integration of this function in the existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup event listeners a little bit different. This is my solution - I belive it's quite clear:

```
var c = document.querySelector('.card'),
    m = document.querySelector('.m'),
    p = document.querySelector('.p'),
    s = document.querySelector('.s'),
    r = document.querySelector('.r'),
    w = c.style.width = '54mm';

var min = false;
var max = false;

m.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
      min = true;
});

m.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    min = false;
});

p.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    max = true;
});

p.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    max = false;
});

s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    r.innerHTML = 54 / parseFloat(w);
});

setInterval(function() {
    if(min) {
        w = c.style.width = parseFloat(w) - 0.5 + 'mm';
    }
}, 100);

setInterval(function() {
    if(max) {
        w = c.style.width = parseFloat(w) + 0.5 + 'mm';
    }
},100);
```